# Magento export products from with an application

Tags: magento, csv, export

I would like to download all the products from a magento site. I have an admin account, and I can open my browser and create an export(csv).  I'm wondering if anyone has tried to do this through code..  Has anyone exported the products without opening a browser?

I am language agnostic (I'll fold in what ever I can or treat it as sudo code) I just don't want to make my user have to manually log into magento and export.

Is there a link or a shortcut, or something that some I'd put after the http://staging.company_name/

---

Oops forgot to mention I don't have access to the box that magento is running on, so I can't add custom scripts or php.  I have to do this through a vanilla install.
My app will eventually pull down from dozens of magento systems for dozens of clients, all the while sitting on a box in some cloud.  
Mote detail  I have a rails app sitting on heroku that can now import files dumped from back ends like ebay and westfield.  It can't however rapidly get products out of magento.. I figured I'd grab the CSV and import it instead of using the soap calls.

Comment: What access do you have??

Comment: I just have username and password to the soap(api), and username and password to the web.  Most of my contact with the clients is with sales-marketing-management.  They are going to sign up with the SAS, fill in 6 or seven fields on a form and my app will clone/sync their Magento instance in my aps format. I can already do this, but the initial product load is heaps slow, and prone to error if ID gaps are too big.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Export product without opening your admin account.

Just create one php file which create export csv file and put it in your root.

So you can able to create file with this url http://staging.company_name/.php file

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
```

Will give you all product collection and then play with this collection.

Comment: Ooops.. I don't have access to the box where magento is installed.. aka I can't add modules to the install.  I am expanding my question. (thanks though)